# Calculating average in awk based on several column conditions in csv

Tags: text-processing, awk, csv, numeric-data

I currently have the following csv format, it's much larger but I've taken a chunk of it for now.

```
EV,"Houston","-7.0"
AB,"Boston","19.0"
OO,"Mystic","13.0"
AB,"Boston","-12.0"
EN,"New York City","9.0"
```

I'd like to calculate the average all positive values of the 3rd column by the first and second columns such that only entries in the second column with Houston and Boston are considered.

I'd like the output to be something like:

```
The average of AB-Boston is 19
The average of EV-Houston is 0
```

I've tried this so far, and it's not a good attempt at all.

```
awk -F, '{airline[$1$2]+=$3;++count[$1]}END{for (key in airline) print "Average of",key,"is",airline[key]/count[key]}' file
```

I've written out a solution in python, but i'm not used to bash and would like to get better at it.

Comment: Does any of the fields contain embedded commas?

Comment: you use `$1$2` for airline sum and `$1` for count.

Comment: No embedded commas!

Comment: `ab c` -> `abc` and `a bc` -> `abc` so don't concatenate fields without including a separator if you want them to be unique for different values of the fields, eg `airline[$1$2]` should instead be `airline[$1,$2]` or `airline[$1 FS $2]` or similar.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As [@Archemar](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/556408/calculating-average-in-awk-based-on-several-column-conditions-in-csv#comment1033531_556408) pointed out, you are using different array keys. I changed them to `$1"-"$2` to better match your output.

Another issue is that fields two and three are quoted which is not so good for the calculation as the values of field3 are treated as zero. A quick fix is to replace all quotes in `$0` with an empty string.

```
awk -F',' '{
  gsub(/"/, "")
  airline[$1"-"$2]+=$3
  ++count[$1"-"$2]
}
END {
  for (key in airline) print "Average of",key,"is",airline[key]/count[key]
}' file
```

Output:

```
Average of EN-New York City is 9
Average of AB-Boston is 3.5
Average of EV-Houston is -7
Average of OO-Mystic is 13
```

If "calculate the average all positive values of the 3rd column" means that only positive values should be considered, then add an `if` statement as below. I'm not completely sure if that's what you want.

```
awk -F',' '{
  gsub(/"/, "")
  if ($3>0) {
    airline[$1"-"$2]+=$3
    ++count[$1"-"$2]
  }
}
END {
  for (key in airline) print "Average of",key,"is",airline[key]/count[key]
}' file
```

Output:

```
Average of EN-New York City is 9
Average of AB-Boston is 19
Average of OO-Mystic is 13
```

Comment: Thank you so much for this, it's not exactly what I want due to me not being clear enough but this is more than enough for me to work with. Thanks again!